# Output of Function to Global Environment in R

Tags: r, function

This might be basic question but I haven't been able to figure it out.

So I have a function which fetches multiple `data.frame` from MySQL Database using `RMySQL` package and perform couple of operations.

I want the output of it to go to global environment, so I can easily run other functions.

**Example**

I did some reading and found that `<<-` can be used for scoping, however it doesn't seems to work.

```
myfunc <- function() {
  `FETCH DF`
  `FETCH DF1`
  `PERFORM OPERATIONS`
  DF <<- DF
  DF1 <<- DF1
}
```

I just want `DF` AND `DF1` to go to global environment so I can perform the following

```
myfunc()
DF <- whateverfunc(DF)
DF1 <- whateverfunc(DF1)
```

**Reproduce**

You guys can run the following to reproduce my sim.

```
myfunc <- function() {
  DF <- data.frame(q = c(503,503,503,503,503), w = c(56,56,56,56,56))
  DF1 <- data.frame(V1 = c("A","B"), V2 = c("C", "D"))

  DF <<- DF
  DF1 <<- DF1
}

myfunc()
```

Comment: how about putting `DF` and `DF1` into a `list` and `return` that `list`?

Comment: Your code puts `DF` and `DF1` into the global environment, exactly like you wanted. But really, you shouldn't be doing it this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in fact very simple. Just think of environments and assign to `.GlobalEnv`.

```
myfunc <- function() {
  DF <- data.frame(q = c(503,503,503,503,503), w = c(56,56,56,56,56))
  DF1 <- data.frame(V1 = c("A","B"), V2 = c("C", "D"))
  .GlobalEnv$DF <- DF
  .GlobalEnv$DF1 <- DF1
}

# only run this if needed
#rm(DF, DF1)

myfunc()
ls(pattern = "DF")
#[1] "DF"  "DF1"
```

And there is **no need for `<<-`**.

Comment: Assigning directly to globalenv has the advantage that it will modify exactly what's intended, without the possibility of intervening environments getting in the way. Other than that, it has the main disadvantage of `<<-`, ie mutable state.